# How do you "disable" oh-my-zsh (and zsh) without uninstalling it?

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I was trying new dev environments including zsh and oh-my-zsh. Now that I have installed oh-my-zsh, it starts by default on my terminals (iTerm2 and terminal) always start with zsh and with the settings on from oh-my-zsh. I was wondering if it was possible to "disable" or stop using zsh and its setup with oh-my-zsh without having to uninstall oh-my-zsh? It would also be nice to know how to turn them back on too.

Currently, my terminals goes into zsh automatically (I think) and use the oh-my-zsh automatically. I want to have more control over that and me able to control both, when the zsh is being used and when the oh-my-zsh features are being used.

One thing I am also interested on knowing is, how do the terminal applications know which shell to start running on start up. That would be nice to be able to control too!

If you explain as much as you can of the "why" of every command you give me, that would useful! :)

---

I am on OS X. Not sure if that matters, but I tend to like answers more that are more applicable to more general Unix environments rather to my own.

Comment: you want to stop using `zsh`? or `oh-my-zsh`? which?

Comment: either and both. i.e. I want to be able to control both, when I am using zsh and oh-my-zsh

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The wording of your question is ambiguous, so I can't tell if you mean you want to stop using `zsh` or you want to stop using `oh-my-zsh`. I will cover both.

#### Disabling `zsh`

Simply run `chsh` and select whatever shell you were using before. If you don't know what shell you were using before, it is almost certainly `bash`. This command changes the "login shell" that is associated with your user. Essentially, it changes your default shell.

You will need to open a new terminal window for changes to take effect. If this does not work, you will need to log out and log back in again to reinitialize your environment.

#### Disabling only `oh-my-zsh`

1. Check if `~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh` exists. It probably does. (This file will have been created when the `oh-my-zsh` installation script moved your previous `.zshrc` out of the way. `.zshrc` is a startup file of `zsh`, similar to `.bashrc` for `bash`.)
2. If it does, do `mv ~/.zshrc ~/.zshrc.oh-my-zsh`. This will put the `oh-my-zsh`-created `.zshrc` out of the way, so we can restore the original, by doing `mv ~/.zshrc.pre-oh-my-zsh ~/.zshrc`.
3. If it does not exist, open `~/.zshrc` in a text editor. Find the line that says `source $ZSH/.oh-my-zsh` and either comment it out or remove it. This will disable the initialization of `oh-my-zsh`.

You will need to restart your shell for changes to take effect.

Comment: I apologize about my wording. I believe I clarified it. Is it clear now? Thanks btw.

Comment: @CharlieParker yeah, I was being lazy. I'll expand the answer, maybe explain a bit of the "why".

Comment: @CharlieParker in case you didn't notice, I updated this answer. let me know if anything can be improved.

Answer (score 17):

[chsh -s /bin/bash](https://github.com/robbyrussell/oh-my-zsh/wiki/FAQ#how-do-i-uninstall-omz-and-zsh)

To manually set a new default shell, do chsh -s /my/
new/shell, eg chsh -s /bin/bash. Then simply reopen your shells.

Comment: Best answer, should be accepted !

Comment: How to change it back to use zsh?

Comment: @ParthTamane chsh -s /bin/zsh

Answer (score 14):

As it's a bit hidden in @Gilles answer the quick way to load zsh without any config e.g. .zshrc .zshenv etc

```
zsh -f
```

This is useful when you want to test if anything in your config is preventing some feature of zsh from working.

Answer (score 3):

**ZSH Config Switching**

If you want to test different zsh configuration frameworks (oh-my-zsh, zprezto, etc) ***and*** switch between them, your best bet is using symbolic links for `~/.zsh`, `~/.zshrc`, `~/.zlogin`, `~/.zlogout`, `~/.zprofile`, and `~/.zshenv`.  You may want to create a shell scripts for each framework to create those symlinks for faster switching.

Put your framework configurations in their own folders.  For each framework.

- Install the framework in its own folder if possible, otherwise
- If the framework forces installation to `~/.zsh`, then

  - Protect the current `~/.zsh` first.  Either

    - remove the `~/.zsh` symlink; `rm ~/.zsh`, or
    - move the `~/.zsh` folder; `mv ~/.zsh ~/.zsh.backup`
  - Run the framework installer.
  - Move the framework folder to its own directory.  e.g. `mv ~/.zsh ~/.oh-my-zsh`.
- Repeat for each framework.

Once done, create a shell script for each framework to create the necessary symlinks.  Here's an example for zprezto, since I already use it.

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ cat <<EOF > ~/bin/use-zprezto
#!/bin/bash
SYMLINKS=".zsh .zshrc .zshlogin .zshlogout .zshprofile .zpreztorc .zshenv .zshrc"
CONFIG_HOME="$HOME/.zprezto"

# check for unexpected error conditions
for sym in $SYMLINKS; do
   # report an error and quit if $sym exists and is not a symlink
   [[ -e "$HOME/$sym" -a ! -h "$HOME/$sym" ]] && { echo "error:  '$HOME/$sym' is not a symlink!"; return 1; }
done

# now create the symlinks now that nothing should go wrong
for sym in $SYMLINKS; do
   # remove old symlink if it exists
   [[ -h "$HOME/$sym" ]] && rm -f "$HOME/$sym"
   # create new symlink
   ln -s "$CONFIG_HOME/$sym" "$HOME/$sym"
done

# uncomment next line to start a new zsh shell.  CAUTION: each call is a zsh shell inside a zsh shell.  Too many calls will put you in limbo :D
#/usr/bin/env zsh
EOF

$ chmod 700 ~/bin/use-zprezto
```

This script is fairly simple and relies on the fact that all my symlinks are organized with the same pattern.  You can copy&paste the *remove* and *create* lines after the loop for symlinks you have that don't follow the pattern.

Once done, use `~/bin/use-zprezto`--or `~/bin/use-whatever`--to switch between zsh frameworks.

Note that changes only take effect in new zsh shells, not existing shells.

**Shell Switching**

It's a bit dangerous, but if you're so inclined, you can use a symlink for your shell command and set the symlink as your default shell.  You can then follow the `use-*` script method above to change your default shell.

As an example with zsh...

```
$ mkdir ~/bin
$ cat <<EOF > ~/bin/use-zsh
#!/bin/bash
# check for valid shell symlink
if [[ ! -h "$HOME/.shell" ]]; then
  echo "error: $HOME/.shell is not a symlink!"
  return 1
fi

# remove existing shell symlink if it exists
[[ -h "$HOME/.shell" ]] && rm -f "$HOME/.shell"

# create new shell symlink, but warn user if this fails!
if ! ln -s /usr/bin/zsh "$HOME/.shell"; then
  echo "ERROR: failed to create $HOME/.shell symlink.  Manually create the symlink or future logins will fail!."
  return 2
fi
EOF

$ chmod 700 ~/bin/use-zsh
```

The reason this is dangerous is that you cannot login under a user if the shell stored in `/etc/passwd` is not a valid program.  So you can lock yourself out of your account if you're not careful; i.e. your `~/.shell` symlink is broke or doesn't point to an interactive program.  You're welcome to try this with a user account, but this is NOT RECOMMENDED for your `root` account.

If you still want to continue, then

```
$ ~/bin/use-zsh         # ensures ~/.shell exists for chsh
$ echo "$HOME/.shell | sudo tee -a /etc/shells    # add symlink to system's list of valid shells
$ chsh -s ~/.shell      # changes default shell in /etc/passwd for $USER
```

Answer (score 3):

You can tell zsh to load its per-user configuration files from a different directory by setting the environment variable [`ZDOTDIR`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Files.html#Startup_002fShutdown-Files) before starting zsh.

If you want to start zsh without loading your configuration files, set `ZDOTDIR` to a non-existent directory. If you want to skip system configuration files (apart from `/etc/zshenv`), you can run `zsh -f`. If you want to skip system configuration files but run the per-user files, run `zsh -d`.

For example, if you want to test-drive oh-my-zsh without making it the default, don't put the `.zshrc` from oh-my-zsh in your home directory. Instead, put it somewhere else, eg. in `~/.oh-my-zsh`, and then run `ZDOTDIR=~/.oh-my-zsh zsh` when you want to use oh-my-zsh.

---

Terminal applications run the shell indicated by the `SHELL` environment variable. If this variable is unset, they run the login shell indicated in the user database (`/etc/passwd`). You can request a different application when you start a terminal emulator, e.g. `xterm -e fish`.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I only wanted to disable the ohmyzsh-behavior when on a nfs mount. The ohmyzsh prompt (with git status) caused terrible delays. But I did want not disable all of the zsh settings because of starting up with -f

With help of Gilles answer I did the following:

- create directory zsh
- copied `~/.zprofile` to `zsh/.zshrc`
- edited out the sourcing of the ohmyzsh-profile in `zsh/.zshrc`
- start a new shell with `ZDOTDIR=$HOME/zsh zsh`

Now a zsh is loaded with all the settings and aliases of the normal .zprofile. Keep in mind that changes in .zprofile are not reflected in zsh/.zshrc. When needed, this has to be solved with includes.